# What kind of error is this sysmalloc: Assertion?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, runtime-error, malloc

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this error and how can I rectify it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char makemeunique(char *s,int l)
{ 
char *xp=(char *)malloc(l*sizeof(char));
int *pp=xp;
for(int i=1;i<l; i++)
{ 
    int yes=0; 
    for(int j=i-1;j>=0; j--)
    {
    if(s[i]==s[j])
    yes=1;
    } 
    if(yes-1)
    *pp++=s[i];
} 

*pp='\0';
printf("%s\n",xp);
return xp;
}
```

Main function

```
int main()
{
char s[9999],x [9999]; 
scanf("%s\n%s",s,x);

char *p1, *p2;

p1=makemeunique(s, strlen(s)); 
p2=makemeunique(x, strlen(x));
}
```

My output:

```
Hello: malloc.c:2385: sysmalloc: Assertion (old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((uns igned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pa gesize - 1)) == 0)' failed. Aborted (core dumped)
```

What is the meaning of this output??

This program simply gets two strings and calls the function and stores created heap array in the pointer.

This is my program and output:
[image: My program]

[image: Test case and output]

Comment: No I need to change

Comment: you store 19KB on the stack

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf`. If it has failed for any reason then `strlen` calls may be operating on unintialised variables. It's basic good programming to do error checking of all functions. For further help please provide the exact input being used for testing.

Comment: The length returned by `strlen` does *not* include the null-terminator. You must remember to add space for it when you allocate your memory. Otherwise the null-terminator will be written out of bounds of the allocated memory, and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: yeah so I used *pp='\0';

Comment: Yeah but you didn't `malloc` enough space for the terminating character if the output string is the same length as the input string. Needs to be `malloc(l+1);`

Comment: Also there's [some discussion about casting the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) and the consensus is "no".

Comment: I also recommend you take this as an opportunity to learn how to use a *debugger* to catch crashes and similar events, and how to locate where in your code it happens, and how to examine variables at that point.

Comment: yeah i will change malloc to malloc(l+1) and check

Comment: but no change every after changing to malloc(l+1);

Comment: Why is `pp` an `int*` ?

Comment: Bro wow Nice I change to char* and got my expected output

Comment: @John3136 Oh that's definitely a major problem! And one that the compiler should be able to catch and warn about.

Comment: Lesson of today: Enable extra warnings, and treat them as errors that *must* be fixed.

Comment: But still I need to know what is the meaning of that error

Comment: You are only dealing with plain text here. Please do not post pictures of plain text. Instead copy&paste it into your question. This also applies to input and output. You already have the code as text. There is absolutely no need to add it as image as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create wrong pointer type at :

```
int *pp=xp;
```

pp should be char* : each time you do *pp++ you add sizeof(int) instead of sizeof(char) : result is you go beyond allocated memory to xp and this can result in usual C undefined behaviour.

Comment: Any idea what is the meaning of the error??

Comment: As I wrote ´undefined behaviour ´ can be anything. You setup a memory place past the end of allocated memory then anything can happen. In this case, It is not necessary to understand what happens in malloc. If you want you may check it source code but that may be waste of time.

Comment: Yeah Now I got the point